# Concatenate multiple lines of a file into one line separated by | (in Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, file-io

I have a multi-line file named sapA.txt like this:

```
sapA
sapB
oppB
oppC
```

I want to concatenate these lines into one line separated by '|'

I have tried the following:

```
File.open("sapA.txt").each do |line|
line.chomp!
end 

array = line.split(" ") 
string = array [0] + '|' + array [1]
puts string
```

however, nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess you should be checking for \r OR \n (newline characters) ?

Comment: It might help if you tagged this question with the name of the language you are using. Or at least mention the language in the question.

Comment: Edited to include that this is using Ruby!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
>> File.open("sapA.txt").map(&:chomp).join("|")
=> "sapA|sapB|oppB|oppC"
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get much simpler than this:

```
File.open('file.txt').split.join
```

Or to meet your spec:

```
File.open('file.txt').split.join('|')
```